# Glassfish internal error unanderstandble

Tags: glassfish, internal-server-error

I have a very easy javascript code inside an xhtml page, but Glassfish doesn't want to render it due an internal error:

```
 javax.servlet.ServletException: Error Parsing /basicuser/singletripcreation.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 14] Il riferimento di entità "callback" deve terminare con il delimitatore ';'.
```

the code involved at the line 14 is the following

```
 <script language="Javascript">
 function loadGoogleMapsScript()
 {
     var script = document.createElement("script");
     script.type = "text/javascript";  
     script.src = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=visualizzamappa";
     document.body.appendChild(script);
 }
 loadGoogleMapsScript();
 </script>
```

the 14th line is "script.src = ...."

what is wrong?! the error looks like inside the string. I this is a compilation error, why the compiler check inside a string?!? (yes the error is shown even before the execution, like compilation error)

How could i solve?!

thankyou very much

---- @Mike

Now the error is on :

```
   for (var x=0; x<indirizzi.length ; x++)
       codifica_indirizzi(indirizzi[x], descrizioni[x]);
```

and say:

```
 javax.servlet.ServletException: Error Parsing /basicuser/singletripcreation.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 47] Il tipo di elemento "indirizzi.length" deve essere seguito dalle specifiche di attributo ">" o "/>".
```

causa principale

"the kind of element 'indirizzi.length' must  be followed by the specificaton ot attribute '>' or '/<'"

Comment: Il riferimento di entità "callback" deve terminare con il delimitatore ';'.   means in english "the reference to the entity callback must terminate with the delimeter ';'."

Comment: The compiler still show an arror on the line 14 even it i put it like a javascript comment .

Comment: Can you add an example of what it looked like after you changed it? Does the error message change?

Answer (score 2):

This answer tells you the problem and how to solve it https://stackoverflow.com/a/14112363/212224

it is the ampersand (&) in the URL that is causing problems. it means that the ...&callback... part of the URL is viewed as an XML element. The & symbol should be replaced by & so the full line 14 should read:

```
script.src = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;callback=visualizzamappa";
```

If you have any other characters causing similar problems, Wikipedia has a list of XML entity names: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Comment: thankyou really much Mike!!! now that error disappeard, but i have another error on 'for (var x=0; x<indirizzi.length; x++)' is **Element type "indirizzi.length" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"** ....

Comment: Hey I solved. Instead write < in the code, just you should use &amp;lt;. It is crazy, but it works. thankyou very much for your help

Comment: No problem. I updated my answer with a link to a Wikipedia page with a list of all the different characters and their entity names for reference.